# Toggling the visibility of a div via JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make it so when I click a button, an overlay "login screen" displays. but my code is not working at all. Here is the HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isOpen = new Boolean(false);

  if (isOpen == true) {
    document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "block";
  } else {

    document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "none";
  }

  $("#login-button").click(function() {
    isOpen != isOpen;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

  <li><a href="#" id="login-button" style="background-color: #404040;">CLIENT AREA</a></li>
  <!--deleted other menu items as they are not important to the issue-->

</ul>

<div id="login-float" style="display: none;">

  <form id="login-mini" action="login-check.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>

      <center>

        <h2>Client Login Area</h2>

      </center>

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">

      <br>

      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">

      <br>

      <center>

        <a href="/contact.php">I can't access my account.</a>

      </center>




    </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
```

I do not have a whole lot of experience with JavaScript and jQuery but I have made scripts that show/hide content before, just haven't made one that toggles visibility, so I'm assuming there is an issue somewhere in there. I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: try `isOpen = !isOpen`

Comment: Move the `if` code `if (isOpen == true) {` inside the click handler (and what @3Dos said).

Comment: Your if statement is only running when the page loads and not when a user clicks #login-button. You should put it inside the clcik event listener your defined.

Comment: what's the status of the question? If an answer solved it, then it should be chosen and accepted in order to mark it as being solved. If you don't know how to do this, ask me/them.

Comment: [This is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your code to

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var isOpen = false;         
      $("#login-button").click(function() {
        isOpen = !isOpen;
        if (isOpen) {
          document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "block";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "none";
        }
      });
    });
```

The code excutes inside the `.click` callback so the conditional should live there. You could clean up the code more but for your understanding this should work :).

Answer (score 2):

Watch out because there are some errors in the code:

With

```
isOpen != isOpen;
```

you aren't assigning a value, it is just a condition. You might want to do this:

```
isOpen = !isOpen;
```

Also, since your check is made inside

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

This only gets evaluated once, after the page loads. You have to put your check inside a function and then call it when needed, for example:

```
function checkOpen(){
    if (isOpen == true) {
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
```

And then call it on click

```
$("#login-button").click(function() {
    isOpen != isOpen;
    checkOpen();
});
```

Comment: ahh that's right != is not equals. For some reason I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 2):

You can change it and make it so much easier with [toggle()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-button").click(function() {
        $("#login-float").toggle()
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

  <li><a href="#" id="login-button" style="background-color: #404040;">CLIENT AREA</a></li>
  <!--deleted other menu items as they are not important to the issue-->

</ul>

<div id="login-float" style="display: none;">

  <form id="login-mini" action="login-check.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>

      <center>

        <h2>Client Login Area</h2>

      </center>

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">

      <br>

      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">

      <br>

      <center>

        <a href="/contact.php">I can't access my account.</a>

      </center>




    </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to achieve what you want without jQuery!

```js
var isOpen = false;

function toggleLogin () {
  if (isOpen === true) {
    document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("login-float").style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener('click', function () {
  isOpen = !isOpen;
  toggleLogin();
});
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

  <li><a href="#" id="login-button" style="background-color: #404040;">CLIENT AREA</a></li>
  <!--deleted other menu items as they are not important to the issue-->

</ul>

<div id="login-float" style="display: none;">

  <form id="login-mini" action="login-check.php" method="post">

    <fieldset>

      <center>

        <h2>Client Login Area</h2>

      </center>

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">

      <br>

      <input class="text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">

      <br>

      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">

      <br>

      <center>

        <a href="/contact.php">I can't access my account.</a>

      </center>




    </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing inline style, create `.hidden` class and toggle it.

```js
$('#login-button').click(function() {
  var loginFloat = $('#login-float');
  if (loginFloat.hasClass('hidden')) {
    loginFloat.removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    loginFloat.addClass('hidden');
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#login-button {
  background: #3bb2c1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#login-float {
  background: #51b7b7;
  margin: 2em;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li><a href="#" id="login-button">CLIENT AREA</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="login-float" class="hidden">
  <form id="login-mini" action="login-check.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <center>
        <h2>Client Login Area</h2>
      </center>
      <br>
      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username">
      <br>
      <input class="text-input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
      <br>
      <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
      <br><br>
      <center>
        <a href="/contact.php">I can't access my account.</a>
      </center>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```